# Records that don't match between different databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query that shows those Clients that don't have an exact match with another system:

```
select *
from CacheClients
Left Join CacheClientsOtherSystem on 
CacheClients.[Client Number] = CacheClientsOtherSystem.Resident and 
CacheClients.[First Name] = CacheClientsOtherSystem.[First name] and 
CacheClients.[Last Name] = CacheClientsOtherSystem.[Last name] and 
CacheClients.[DOB] = CacheClientsOtherSystem.[Date of Birth] and 
CacheClients.[Street Address] = CacheClientsOtherSystem.[Street name] and 
CacheClients.[Post Code] = CacheClientsOtherSystem.[Postcode] and
CacheClients.[Suburb] = CacheClientsOtherSystem.[City/Suburb] and 
CacheClients.[State] = CacheClientsOtherSystem.[State] and
CacheClients.[Export Code]  = CacheClientsOtherSystem.[Facility No] and
CacheClients.[Funding ID] = CacheClientsOtherSystem.[Accomodation History   No] and
CacheClients.[Export Code] = CacheClientsOtherSystem.[Facility No]  and
CacheClients.[Client Status] = CacheClientsOtherSystem.[Archived]
where [Export Code] = '420022' --412030
and ([Latest End Date] is null or [Latest End Date] > Convert(Date, GetDate()))
```

The problem I need to solve is having a Message column that says what it doesn't match on for each individual row, i.e. "Does not match on DOB, Post Code, State" as an example.

I was wondering if anyone had any clever ideas for achieving that?

Comment: Best I can think of is concatenating multiple `case` statement...

Comment: `CASE WHEN CacheClientsOtherSystem.[Client Number] IS NULL THEN '[Client Number],' ELSE '' END + CASE WHEN CacheClientsOtherSystem.[First Name] IS NULL THEN '[First Name]' ELSE '' END + ..... `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are matching on `clientnumber` and `clientnumber` is unique in both tables, then you can use `join` to get matching records.  A `case` statement can identify when the columns match.  The following is the basic logic (although this doesn't take `NULL` values into account):

```
select cc.clientnumber,
       stuff((case when cc.[First Name] = ccos.[First Name] then '' else ',First Name'
              end) +
             (case when cc.[Last Name] = ccos.[Last Name] then '' else ',Last Name'
              end) +
             . . .
             , 1, 1, '')
from CacheClients cc join
     CacheClientsOtherSystem ccos
     on cc.clientnumber = ccos.clientnumber;
```